# Typo on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, spelling

When a proposal is in the Commitment phase and you click on any of the left-hand side links (great on-topic example, great off-topic example, not a good example) a notification comes up with the following..

> This proposal is in the Commitment phase
>
> This proposal received enough
>   questions and followers to enter the
>   Commitment phase. The Commitment phase
>   is a ***peition*** to have the site created.

Surely this should be ***petition***?

Comment: They are aliens, english is not their first language.

Comment: What do you mean?  "Peition" is a perfectly cromulent word.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed, though I think [Kop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140478/kop)'s comment above is the correct answer:

> They are aliens, english is not their
>   first language. – [Kop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140478/kop)

Comment: I sure hope he has been neuralized since, to avoid him spreading the fact that you are in fact ali... oh, what a pretty red light.